# Prevent left div from sliding out of the browser when the browser is narrower

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to it be responsive keep in mind. When dragging my browser from the right to the left. The pic div would be pushed out of the browser. Do I not have my content centered correctly? I'm not sure If I have to use media queries or not.If so I have no knowledge of it. So please be detailed for me.

CSS:

```
 body {
     background-color: #333435;
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
 }
 .container {
     height: 500px;
     width:800px;
     margin: -250px 0 0 -400px;
     position: absolute;
     left:50%;
     top:50%;
 }
 .time {
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
     margin: auto;
     margin-bottom: -20px;
     font-family:"Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
     font-style: italic;
     font-size: 100px;
     color:#d6d6d6;
     padding-top: 30px;
 }
 #date {
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
     margin: auto;
     font-family:"Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
     color:#d6d6d7;
 }
 #main {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 346px;
     margin-top: 35px;
 }
 .logo {
     background-image: url('images/logo.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     float:left;
     width: 25%;
     height: 100%;
     display: block;
 }
 .portaltext {
     width:240px;
     height:34px;
     background-image: url('images/portal.png');
     float: left;
     clear: both;
     position: relative;
     top: 94px;
 }
 .divider {
     background-color:#008000;
     float:left;
     width: 25%;
     height: 100%;
 }
 #loginform {
     background-color:#A52A2A;
     float:left;
     width: 25%;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="time">12:22 PM</div>
        <div id="date">Friday, September, 12, 2014</div>
        <div id="main">
            <div class="logo">
                <div class="portaltext"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <div id="loginform"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Where's the "pic" div?

Comment: You may want to look into [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) frameworks for responsive design rather than reinvent the wheel.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

the thing i can understand from your question is that when you resize the browser the image pushed out of the screen if thats the problem it is happening because of negative margin you can solve it using media query

```
@media screen and ( max-width:800px)
{
.container {

     margin:0px;
     left:0%;
 }
}
```

i think it will help otherwise sorry